# Setting FQDN/DNS Suffix with Vagrant

Tags: dns, vagrant, fqdn

Is there any way to set up primary DNS suffix for Windows boxes? I took a look to Google and couldn't find anything for Windows.

I easily set host name on Vagrantfile and define networks.

```
  # Update IP Address
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.0.0.100", bridge: "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet"
  config.windows.set_work_network = true

  # Host name is shown as device name on C1
  config.vm.host_name = "HOSTNAME"
```

[image: Primary DNS Suffix]

Comment: you could use a [powershell script](https://github.com/cajeeper/PowerShell/blob/master/Update-HostFQDN.ps1) run during provision of the VM to do this

Comment: @FrédéricHenri is there any example? EDIT: I see your link. Thanks, I'll take a look